# "Виставочний" чи "виставковий"?

Tags: вибір-слова, прикметники

Нещодавно, редагуючи текст, натрапила на словосполучення **виставочна  зала** і не задумуючись виправила на **виставкова**. Однак, отримала примітку, що слово **виставочна** теж нормативне в українській мові. В [СУМі в 11 т.](http://sum.in.ua/s/vystavochnyj) знайшла:

> **ВИ́СТАВОЧНИЙ**, а, е. Прикм. до виставка.

Однак, в [СУМі в 20 т.] появляється позначка *рідко*:

> **ВИ́СТАВОЧНИЙ**, а, е, **рідко**. Те саме, що виставко́вий.

У статті [Типові помилки в «Інтегрованій лексикографічній системі»](https://r2u.org.ua/node/268) знаходжу:

> слова-покручі в реєстрі: вищестоящий, понятійний, оціночний, **виставочний.**..

Отже, чи є нормативним вживання слова **виставочний**. Чи вважатиметься це помилкою, наприклад, у творах ЗНО (зважаючи на позначку **рідко**).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Все ж, якщо це слово зазначається в СУМі, то виходить, що його вживання можливе. Також бачимо це слово в [Орфографічному словнику української мови](http://www.rozum.org.ua/index.php?a=term&d=21&t=39530).

Але все ж гадаю, що ви праві і, наприклад у творах ЗНО, краще вживати прикметник "виставковий". Згідно до інформації у бозі проф. Пономарева: "Коли йдеться про документ під час посадки на літак, то ліпше використовувати посадковий, а не посадочний талон. Порівняйте: станція метрополітену в Києві **Виставковий** (а **не виставочний**) центр". Те саме у нас із [економічним терміном](http://slovopedia.org.ua/38/53399/379815.html) - "зразок виставковий", а не "виставочний". А [переклад](https://uk.glosbe.com/ru/uk/%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9) російського "выставочный" на українську також дає варіант "виставковий". Також маємо приклади із словників на [Академіку](https://translate.academic.ru/%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B9/uk/): виставковий маникен, виставковий стенд, виставкова зала. І в [Орфографічному словнику](http://www.rozum.org.ua/index.php?a=term&d=21&t=39513) це слово також зустрічається.